# All possibilities of string x using certain characters - Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, permutation

How would I find all possibilities of a 10 char string using the chars "a","b" and "c". I know there are 3^10 possibilities but I'm not sure how to code it. I know there's a good chance there's already an answer for this but I just can't find it. Thanks.

EDIT

I've already tried to do it using the itertools module, in particular using the permutations and combinations modules but all to no avail.

Comment: Take a look at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

Comment: I have and I've tried to use itertools.permutations but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe how it didn't meet your requirements?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't do it on this computer so I don't have the code with me. I think I deleted it when it didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module. `map("".join, itertools.product('abc', repeat=10))` should do the job.